# Statistics in circuits

Tags: statistics

I have a circuit, in order for it to work the electricity has to travel from point $A$ to point $B$, but on its way there it encounters $4$ independent switches. If any one of them is closed the system will function properly. the probability of a switch being closed is $.3$ for all $4$ switches, what is the overall probability that the system functions.

Currently I tried using a tree diagram but that offered me no help and quickly just made it more confusing. im not sure where to even begin or what to start with

Comment: Could you have solved the problem if there were only two switches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the probability of at least 1 switch being closed. An easy way to do this is to find the probability that all the switches aren't closed are take the complement. $P(\mbox{All switches are open})=(.7)^4=0.2401$. Thus, $P(\mbox{At least one switch is closed})=1-0.2401=0.7599$

Comment: so how would you fine the probability that at least 3 switches are activated?

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this, solve the probability that the system will fail.  Then subtract that number from 1 to get the probability it will not fail.

For it to fail, all switches would have to fail.  That probability would be $${0.7}^4$$

Subtract that from 1 to get your answer.

Your tree diagram would also work.  It would need to be 4 tiers.  You would find that all paths work except for the path where all 4 switches failed.  The sum of the 15 other paths is found the same way I detailed above.

Comment: I understood "open" to mean "fail" and OP only needed one to be closed to function (parallel).  I could be wrong though.